# How do I retrieve the top two values in an index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm iterating through an index and printing out some values with this:

```
fl = gis.content.get(fl_item_id).layers[fl_item_idx].query(where="City = 'Round Rock'", order_by_fields='Date_Confirmed DESC' ).sdf

for index, total in fl.iterrows():
    print(total['Cumulative_Totals'])
```

which results in:

```
4020
3965
3937
3880
3832
3775
3714
3699
3670
3615
3533
3502
3475
3441
3371
3338
3314
3275
3258
3256
3221
3198
3178
3162
```

I'd like to grab the top two values from the output above and assign them to a variable. I was thinking I need to wrap this in a *for i in range(2)* somehow...

fl looks like this:

```
OBJECTID    Date_Confirmed  City    Cumulative_Totals
0   324541  2020-12-02 06:00:00 Round Rock  4020
1   324540  2020-12-01 06:00:00 Round Rock  3965
2   324539  2020-11-30 06:00:00 Round Rock  3937
3   324538  2020-11-29 06:00:00 Round Rock  3880
4   324537  2020-11-28 06:00:00 Round Rock  3832
... ... ... ... ...
237 324304  2020-03-27 05:00:00 Round Rock  8
238 324303  2020-03-25 05:00:00 Round Rock  6
239 324302  2020-03-24 05:00:00 Round Rock  5
240 324301  2020-03-22 05:00:00 Round Rock  2
241 324300  2020-03-19 05:00:00 Round Rock  1
```

Comment: `for idx, total in fl[:2].iterrows()`?

Comment: Thanks. That gets me the top two values. Now I need to assign each of those top two values their own variable.

Comment: You can use: `my_var = [total['Cumulative_Totals'] for idx,total in fl[:2].iterrows()]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To grab the first `n` elements of an iterator as a list you can use `list(itertools.islice(it, n))`.

Or if you only want that specific field:

```
cumtotals = [total['Cumulative_Totals']
             for _, total in itertools.islice(fl.iterrows(), 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try using slicing syntax, for example `fl[0:2]` to get the first two items from your variable, but I don't know which data type is your variable fl, must be an iterable to work properly.

Comment: Thanks. I'll edit the original question to include what fl looks like.